# How to know when there is input through the terminal pipe line on C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, posix

#### How to know when there is input through the terminal pipe line on C++ 11?

I may call my program like this:

```
1. ./main solved.txt
2. cat unsolved.txt | ./main
3. cat unsolved.txt | ./main solved.txt
```

I am using this to know whether I need to read data from the pipe line or not on C POSIX Standard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argumentsCount, char* argumentsStringList[] )
{
    std::stringstream inputedPipeLineString;

    if( argumentsCount > 1 )
    {
        printf( "argumentsStringList[1]: %s", argumentsStringList[ 1 ] );
    }

    // If it is passed input through the terminal pipe line, get it.
    if( !isatty( fileno( stdin ) ) )
    {
        // Converts the std::fstream "std::cin" to std::stringstream which natively
        // supports conversion to string.
        inputedPipeLineString << std::cin.rdbuf();

        printf( "inputedPipeLineString: %s", inputedPipeLineString.str().c_str() );
    }
}
```

But now I want to use the C++ 11 Standard, and my loved `fileno` and `isatty` are out of it. So there is an alternative to them on the C++ 11?

Related threads:

1. [checking data availability before calling std::getline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3317740/4934640)
2. [Why does in_avail() output zero even if the stream has some char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17474252/4934640)
3. [Error "'fdopen' was not declared" found with g++ 4 that compiled with g++3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15944051/4934640)
4. [stdio.h not standard in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7596406/4934640)
5. [error: ‘fileno’ was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29692136/4934640)
6. [GoogleTest 1.6 with Cygwin 1.7 compile error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18784112/4934640)

The problem is that when compiling with the `-std=C++11`, the `fileno` and `isatty` are undefined on the `stdio.h/cstdlib` because they are POSIX stuff. So, one solution would be to use `-std=GNU++11` instead of `-std=C++11`. But is it possible to write something else to compile using the `-std=C++11`?

Comment: There is no portable way I am aware of. What I normally do is use the pipe if there is no command line parameter present.

Comment: POSIX doesn't disappear into thin air just because C++11 appears.  The `fileno` and `isatty` functions were never a part of C++.

Comment: What is the problem with -std=gnu++11 ?

Comment: That's could be tricky, but you can check if a `cin` will perform a blocking read with `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()`. If it returns 0, it's likely that there's no input data pending to be read (a subsequent read wouldn't wait for user input) and thus no pipeline, unless the user could write something in microseconds, of course. A subsequent non-blocking read can be seen has an indirect proof of pipeline presence (or `<<<` input).

Comment: `std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` is always returning 0. Seems a bug on GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24206, but we almost got it working.

Comment: What @Galik said.

Comment: @addons_zz I got that working in the past but first I had to decouple the streams from `stdio` using `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` But I could not find support for it in the standard so who knows if it will work from one version of the compiler to another?

Comment: When I got working on this, I will to find a way creating another thread to get the information, then if after a certain minimum time it does not respond, then I assume there is not input from the sdt::in and kill it.

Comment: `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` has nothing to do with it whatsoever. It is not a bug. It is simply not supposed to work this way.

Comment: Under POSIX, `fileno(stdin)` is the same as `STDIN_FILENO` which is defined as 0. No need to call this function. You only need `isatty`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> C++ POSIX Standard

As far as I know, there is no such thing. There is a **C** POSIX library, which is part of POSIX standard.

> So there is an alternative to them on the C++ 11?

There is no alternative in standard C++ (not before C++11, so far not after either).

You will need to depend on POSIX to get the functionality that you need.

Even in POSIX, it is the `unistd.h` which defines `isatty`. You've neglected to include it in your program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a completely portable way to do this. As far as I know, standard C++ knows no information of where it's input comes from so you should just use `isatty` if you are working on a posix system.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, you have the `<filesystem>` header which has a `std::filesystem::status()` function that returns a `file_status` object. You can access its type through the `type()` function, via the result for instance, and use a quick comparison to see if it's a type of your intended target.
One really naïve approach to this would be something like:

```
auto result {std::filesystem::status(fd)};
if (result.type() == std::filesystem::file_type::character)
{
   // do some stuff in here 
}
```

where fd is the file descriptor to check. The above isn't full proof since there's no additional checks, but if it's a character type, it can almost certainly be equated to a terminal.
If you have a compiler that supports C++17, `<filesystem>` can be really handy
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_type

NOTE: I am just starting out with working with `<filesystem>` so there may be some nuances I'm missing here and welcome any updates to the answer